# How to set a variable which include another variable in dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here is my Query:-

```
declare @a nvarchar (150)
declare @b nvarchar (100)
set @b= 'Test'
set @a =('select COUNT(*) from ' +@b + '.dbo.t_ddl_log')
exec (@a)
if (@a='0')
print 'True'
else
print 'False'
```

It is always printing False even though it should print True.
If I change the variable @b with Test in my count query it works fine.
What is the problem in the query??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the query - the problem is that you mistakenly think that `@a` should hold the results of the query, while in fact it holds the query itself.

You can use `sp_executeSql` to get the results you want:

```
declare @a nvarchar (150),
        @b nvarchar (100),
        @c int
set @b= 'Test'
set @a =('select @count = COUNT(*) from ' +@b + '.dbo.t_ddl_log')

exec sp_executeSql @a, N'@count int output', @c = @count output

if (@c= 0)
    print 'True'
else
    print 'False'
```

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)